# \hfill not wide enough

Tags: cv, parskip

I am refuacturing my cv in latex, but I have a problem with the \hfill command which I use to align text right-flushed on ther same line.

This is what it looks like:
(notice, the years are not aligned to the right except the last line)
[image]

I was able to narrow it down to the `%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` or `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` commands. It seems like the parindent is missing in the `hfill`.

Are there any recommendations how I can fix this?

Here is a little script which shows how this page is generated:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\newcommand{\entry}[3]{
    \textbf{#1}
    
    #2 \hfill \textit{#3}
}

\newcommand{\hr}{
    \vspace{0.7em}\hrule\vspace{.7em}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \entry{Lorem Ipsum \\ Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{2018 - 2020}
    \hr
    \entry{Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{seit 2017}
    \hr
    \entry{Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{seit 2014}
    \hr
    \entry{Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, \\ Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{seit 2006}
    \hr
    \entry{Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{seit 2019}
    \hr
    \entry{Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{2007 - 2014}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are introducing a lot of spurious spaces, But why don't you use a tabular?

Comment: What dou you mean with "spurious spaces"? I thought using a table was way more hacky than using hfill.

Comment: use `\hfill \textit{#3}\par` to end the paragraph and `\usepackage[parfill=0pt]{parskip}
`

Comment: `\newcommand{\hr}{` adds a space (a newline is a space,but here you need `\par` not just comment out thenewline` Your `\entry` macro adds _lots_ of white space

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This helped me, thanks. I still do not understand 100% why, but as long as it works I'm okay with it.

Answer (score 2):

With your definition you are introducing in principle two spurious spaces

```
\newcommand{\entry}[3]{     % <-- here
    \textbf{#1}
    
    #2 \hfill \textit{#3}   % <-- here
}
```

The first might not have effect in the way you are using it, but keep it in mind. Furthermore, when you use

```
\entry{...}{...}{...}
```

there is also a further space, unless you put an explicit `%` at the end of the line. The spurious space in the last line was removed by the implicit new paragraph issued by the following blank line, but the other ones are there.

This being said, here is one suggestion:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{foo}{%
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
   \def\@tempa{\def\@tempa{\par\vspace{.7em}\hrule\vspace{.7em}}}%
   \newcommand*{\entry}[3]{%
      \@tempa
      \textbf{\ignorespaces##1}\par##2\hfill##3%
   }%
   \par
 }{\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
\entry{Lorem Ipsum \\ Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{2018 - 2020}
\entry{Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{seit 2017}
\entry{Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{seit 2014}
\entry{Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, \\ Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{seit 2006}
\entry{Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{seit 2019}
\entry{Lorem Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}{2007 - 2014}
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I prefer defining an environment, but that is my coding taste.